# Ошибка при использовании mysql_fetch_row на php

Tags: php

Не работает следующий кусок кода:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM reg_users WHERE LOWER(email)='".strtolower($mailto)."'");
$rr = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/registration/forgot.php on line 50
```

Хотя прямой запрос к базе данных выдает одну строчку результата
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не отловлена возможная ошибка.

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
if(!$rs){die("Query Error")}
$rr = mysql_fetch_row($rs);`
```

Проблема в том, что если возникает ошибка в запросе и вы передаёте значение mysql_fetch_row, то она ругается на то, что ей скормили не дескриптор таблицы